# Image scraping with cheerio (node.js) not working

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to get article images from Google shopping. For this I am using cheerio and nodejs. So if I'm surfing to a link for a xbox for example (https://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&hl=de-de&tbs=vw:l&q=xbox) and I'm inspecting the image in the developer tools I get a very long base64 string. But when doing the same in cheerio I get a string that looks something like this:
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==

Furthermore when opening it in Chrome it gets encoded as webp.

I already tried changing my User-Agent with the following code:

```
var customHeaderRequest = request.defaults({
    headers: {'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'},
});
```

But still I get shortened image-data. What else could I try to get the whole image-string with cheerio?

Edit: **How to recreate the error:**

At first you have to create a custom Header request with the given user agent. Then you pass to it the url mentioned above (xbox Google shopping), this should return a body variable with the html-code inside which you can pass on to cheerio (I also built in a little code to save a dump of the code to see how the server responds in contrast to how cheerio processes it). It should then look for the given classes which include the image with the base64 data. On the console you should now see the malformed data.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');


var customHeaderRequest = request.defaults({
    headers: {'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'},
});

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&hl=de-de&tbs=vw:l&q=xbox';

customHeaderRequest.get(url, function(err, resp, body) {

    //write curled body to a file for further inspection
    fs.writeFile("dump.html", body, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("file saved");
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });

    $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('.sh-dlr__list-result .sh-dlr__content').each((index, value) => {

        let entryObj = {};
        //image
        $(value).find('.TL92Hc').each(function (idx, ele) {
            //image
            console.log($(ele).attr('src'));

        });
    });

});
```

If I execute this script it gives me the following output:

> C:\mydir>node reproduce_error.js
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==

Comment: When you use the inspector you get a base64 string. When you use cheerio you get a base64 string. Whats the problem?

Comment: The base64 string is literally what I get back.. its with a bunch of ///// in between and virtually no image data

Comment: The Base64 alphabet includes `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `+` and `/`. Are you sure you are selecting the right element? Could we see the code that gets the base64 data?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question. You should now be able to recreate my error. Sorry that I haven't thought of that in the beginning